# web grid server pagination trigger multiple controller call when changing page

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

When I server-filter on "au" my web grid and change page, multiple call to the controller are done :

1. the first with 0 filtering,
2. the second with "a" filtering,
3. the third with "au" filtering.

My table load huge data so the first call is longer than others.
I see the grid displaying firstly the third call result, then the second, and finally the first call (this order correspond to the response time of my controller due to filter parameter)

Why are all that controller call made ? 
Can't just my controller be called once with my total filter "au" ?
What should I do ?

Here is my grid :

```
$("#" + gridId).kendoGrid({
            selectable: "row",
            pageable: true,
            filterable:true,
            scrollable : true,
            //scrollable: {
            //    virtual: true //false // Bug : Génère un affichage multiple...
            //},
            navigatable: true,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: {
                mode: "multiple", // enables multi-column sorting
                allowUnsort: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverGrouping:false, // Ne fonctionne pas...
                pageSize: '@ViewBag.Pagination',
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: Procvalue + "/LOV",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                        // Mise à jour du format d'envoi des paramètres 
                        // pour qu'ils puissent être correctement interprétés côté serveur.
                        // Construction du paramètre sort : 
                        if (options.sort != null) {
                            var sort = options.sort;
                            var sort2 = "";
                            for (i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
                                sort2 = sort2 + sort[i].field + '-' + sort[i].dir + '~';
                            }
                            options.sort = sort2;
                        }
                        if (options.group != null) {
                            var group = options.group;
                            var group2 = "";
                            for (i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
                                group2 = group2 + group[i].field + '-' + group[i].dir + '~';
                            }
                            options.group = group2;
                        }
                        if (options.filter != null) {
                            var filter = options.filter.filters;
                            var filter2 = "";
                            for (i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
                                // Vérification si type colonne == string.
                                // Parcours des colonnes pour trouver celle qui a le même nom de champ.
                                var type = "";
                                for (j = 0 ; j < colonnes.length ; j++) {
                                    if (colonnes[j].champ == filter[i].field) {
                                        type = colonnes[j].type;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (filter2.length == 0) {
                                    if (type == "string") { // Avec '' autour de la valeur.
                                        filter2 = filter2 + filter[i].field + '~' + filter[i].operator + "~'" + filter[i].value + "'";
                                    } else { // Sans '' autour de la valeur.
                                        filter2 = filter2 + filter[i].field + '~' + filter[i].operator + "~" + filter[i].value;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (type == "string") { // Avec '' autour de la valeur.
                                        filter2 = filter2 + '~' + options.filter.logic + '~' + filter[i].field + '~' + filter[i].operator + "~'" + filter[i].value + "'";
                                    }else{
                                        filter2 = filter2 + '~' + options.filter.logic + '~' + filter[i].field + '~' + filter[i].operator + "~" + filter[i].value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            options.filter = filter2;
                        }
                        var json = JSON.stringify(options);
                        return json;
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        return eval(data.data.Data);
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        return eval(data.data.Total);
                    }
                },
                filter: {
                    logic: "or",
                    filters:filtre(valeur)
                }
            },
            columns: getColonnes(colonnes)
        });
```

Here is my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LOV([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(CProduitsManager.GetProduits().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 correspond to the initial load (no filtering) and the following ones as you type in the condition of filter, similar in `kendoAutocomplete` but in `kendoAutocomplete` there are a couple of options (time and min length) that control when to send the requests (I couldn't find anything similar in grid).

If your problem is loading a huge amount of data I do recommend limiting the size of the data transmitted using `pageSize` in the `DataSource` definition. But, obviously, this is not a solution if what takes long is executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios it is recommended to create a typing delay and thus perform a request when the user has stopped typing (unless he is typing slower than regular typing).

To create a delay I can suggest you the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">        
    var globalTimeout = null;
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
        if (globalTimeout != null) clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
        globalTimeout = setTimeout(SearchFunc, 500);
    });   

    function SearchFunc(){  
        globalTimeout = null;
        $('#yourGridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({ field:"theField",operator:"startswith",value:$('#searchInput').val() })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It seems like even with a timer there is something in the grid that saves the successive filters : If I type "au", display the results, and then backspace to "a", and re-display the results, when I change the page the grid calls 2 times my controller... Is there a way to disable this functionality ?